# Issue of jquery show,hide,slidetoggle with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Here my `HTML`

```
<!-- this is my link -->
<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='show_hide'>Show Hide</a>
<!-- This is my show hide content -->
<div class='slidingDiv'> ..................Here my content...............</div>
```

I am Jquery beginner. I just try to build a slide bar. I use `parent().next()` in my `slideToggle()` function. Beacuse I need show/hide for each `DIV`. So I write this code ....

```
$(".show_hide").show();
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$('.show_hide').click(function () {
   $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
});
```

This code is work well. But now my problem is I need cookie for resting after refresh. I write this code

```
var cook= $.cookie('showdiv');
if(cook=='true')
    $(".slidingDiv").show();
else
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();

    $('.show_hide').on('click', function()
    {
            $(this).parent().next().slideToggle('normal', function(){
                $.cookie('showdiv', $(this).is(':visible'));
            });
    });
```

But cookie doesn't work. Note that I'm sure I succesfully install jquery cookie plugin.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/qUngV/, error in console?

Comment: Please provide your html markup too

Comment: Please the resultant HTML markup not the PHP code

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, by storing a boolean value in cookie to check whether true or false, you have to compare it as a string in return.

Have you checked with console.log or alert the return of your cookie?

```
console.log($.cookie('showdiv'));
```

I tested and compared as string had no problems.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D6EEP/)

Answer (score 0):

If the posted is your HTML markup the selector must be `$(this).next(".slidingDiv")` without parent.

Code:

```
var cook = $.cookie('showdiv');
console.log(cook)
if (cook == 'true') $(".slidingDiv").show();
else $(".slidingDiv").hide();

$('.show_hide').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle('normal', function () {
        $.cookie('showdiv', $(this).is(':visible'));
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/PRDU7/

Comment: OK 2 hours later I got the problem not solution. Note that always cookie work. your js fiddle and my code shows only one div and link But there are many `.slidingDiv` group for each `show_hide` button.First I say without `parent()` doesn't work my code. Second I have many `.show_hide` button. So `$(this).parent().next().slideToggle` perform each `.show_hide` button. But when cookie is enable, all `.slidingDiv` shows not specific group `.slidingDiv` of a `show_hide` button. So cookie cant Identify which button is open or close. cookie perform all button not specific `.show_hide`button